# In Keras, how to load the best weights saved during training by the ModelCheckpoint callback?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

From [the doc](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/), I use:

```
checkpoint_filepath = 'tmp/checkpoint'
model_checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
        save_weights_only=True,
        monitor='val_loss',
        mode='min',
        save_best_only=True)
```

But when running the training, I get:

> OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name =
> ......./tmp/checkpoint', errno = 21, error message = 'Is a directory', flags = 13, o_flags =
> 242)

Which indicates that the 'checkpoint_filepath' must be a path toward a file (and not a directory), so I replaced it with:

```
checkpoint_filepath = 'tmp/checkpoint/weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5'
```

But then, when I want to load the network (and to retrieve **the best weights of course**, the ones that correspond to the lowest val_loss!) with (also from the doc):

```
net.load_weights('tmp/checkpoint')
```

I get:

> OSError: Unable to open file (file read failed: time = Sun Nov 20
> 09:39:54 2022 , filename =
> ......../tmp/checkpoint', file descriptor = 27, errno = 21, error message = 'Is a directory',
> buf = 0x7ffeae8d2e50, total read size = 8, byt)

So, how do I load the weights with Keras so that it loads the best weights that were saved by the *ModelCheckpoint* callback ?

Comment: You need to give a path to a HDF5 file, not a folder.

Comment: But how does Keras knows which is the best HDF5 to load ?

Comment: I am using ModelCheckpoint so it will store better and better weights (according to some metrics, here the loss) and in this end I want to load the best weights among all these files.

Comment: Ok I get it, I should save a unique file a load a unique file as well ;)